# Accessing non-public photos in Flickr API

Tags: flickr

[image: Flickr API explorer page]

I'm developing an app that gets photos from Flickr with Javascript. Photoset ID that shown in image is not public hence when i select the "don't sign call" option, API responses "error". I don't want make my Flickr photos public but i want call them from another page via API. I know that it's possible with *"token"*. But token is required going "Login Page".

Can it is possible accessing non-public photos with my API Key?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your app can access your private photos.  You will need to learn about Flickr's [user authentication API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html), which uses the OAuth protocol.  It's a little tricky to get started with, but there are [third-party libraries](http://oauth.net/code/) to help with some of the work.